# Raising a sunken living room floor and concerned about moisture under new raised floor

Tags: framing, subfloor, moisture

I am raising a sunken living room floor but have some concerns about possible moisture problems under this raised floor.  Here is what I have.

A 1979 typical ranch style.  It is roughly a 16 x 20 room with a 5 1/2" drop down.  At one end is an exterior wall with a brick fireplace that has had a leak that has been repaired.  On the opposite end is a wall with plumbing for the laundry room that has twice over the last 10 or so years had a water leak but now repaired and OK.  Add to this, as we were removing the laminate flooring that was in the sunken living area we notice the underside of the foam pad/vapor barrier under the laminate floor was moist as we rolled it up.

My concern is what moisture problems could I have under the void area?  Should I seal the slab floor or will there be enough air in the void area to keep what moisture may develop there from being a problem?

My plan was to build the floor up using 1/2" pressure treated slats under a 2x4 frame and then top that with 2 layers of 23/32 subfloor.  The 1/2 pressure treated at slab contact for any possible moisture issue.

I can install air registers in some areas if I need to allow for air movement under this floor as well as access for inspection if needed. Another thought was to install ports used for a central vacuum system to be able to access the void and blow air through if needed.

Am I overthinking this or do my concerns about the void area under the floor seem valid?  Vinyl laminate will be on top of the subfloor.

Comment: Where is the moisture coming from? Why do you think leaving the existing solution in place is inadequate? Regarding the air register idea, I would seek to avoid circulating musty slab moisture into your living space unless you think it's very minor.

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: Don't lay down your 1/2" slats. Instead, build your floor framing and shim it up to level using shims of the necessary thickness. Your slab is not flat and your plan will need a lot of fixing up (intermediate shimming) to get the wood framing flat. A laser level (borrowed or rented) could be helpful. The shims would need to be every 48" or so--whatever you consider a suitable span for a 2x4 floor joist. Single subfloor should be fine--it's expensive.

Comment: I don't think you should leave a void under the new floor, between the subfloor and the existing concrete slab.  If you do that, you need to provide for some air circulation.  I defer to others as the proper way to fill in the cavity if that's what needs to be done.

Comment: If this floor was in an interior area with no concern for water getting under it then I would not have a concern.  But I do not want to find a pool under the floor at sometime or start getting a musty odor down the road and have to rip it all out.

Comment: I think you need to identify the nature of the settlement - is it the concrete floor only, or foundation; is it uniform 5.5" throughout, where the intrusion water came from, finally is this is the first floor or the basement? Without addressing these issues, you might wound up wasting your time and money.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck using 2 part epoxy paint to seal concrete basement slabs. The one problem you would need to wait until summer when the ground water issue would be reduced if you put a piece of plastic down and 24 hours it is wet underneath that is two wet for the paint I use.

I would want some kind of seal or you may end up with unhealthy growths on the wood in that void.

You may be able to dig a small sump outside and pump the ground water away from the home and put a fan on the slab to dry it out. If that area is close to an exterior wall 18” deep may be enough , I have used a 5 gallon bucket with a bunch of holes as a temporary sump in the past with a little giant pump and a garden hose worked to keep a home from flooding until a permanent drain could be installed.

Comment: This is grade level in Texas so there is not an issue with ground water to need a sump pump.  I do think I am going to put a sealer on the slad so that it is a clean area under the floor.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is the water from past leaks? I ask as I have had issues with a slab that had a spring under it not a basement on grade, we did create a drain to deal with that. That’s why I mentioned the temp sump to be able dry out the area and seal it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what my builder was supposed to do with a similar situation - new living space built over an existing concrete slab for a garage.

1) Fill with crushed, well draining stone

2) Lay down  6 mil vapor barrier on top of the stone

3) Pour 4" concrete slab up to 1-1/2" below the level of the existing concrete block.

4) Install 2x8 floor joists

5) Insulate between the floor joists

6) Install subfloor

7) Install final flooring

Comment: All told, this'd raise the floor level by a good foot and a half. The OP has maybe a third of that to work with.

Comment: Yes, that was how far the existing garage slab was below the floor of the house.  I agree, OP's situation is different.  I just wanted to give him a point of reference to use going forward.

Comment: Why the down vote???  After 3-1/2 years?

Comment: Wasn't me, but: the OP has a 5.5 inch dropdown. You described what your builder did with your foot-and-a-half dropdown. Absent any tips on how to fit 18 inches of material into less than 6 inches (dimensional portals being really hard to get these days), "this answer is not useful" seems to be an accurate statement. The elapsed years do not magically give your answer more usefulness, sorry.